# Adding a header navigational bar to LaTeX beamer (also when \thispagestyle{empty})

Tags: beamer, presentations, navigation

I am trying to find a nice way to integrate a navigation bar/section overview with my presentation. I found the following code block, which adds a horizontal bar with the sections above the frame header and I like it.

```
% ADD bar with sections above header
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I use: `\thispagestyle{empty}`, the bar is hidden and the space becomes white. Which is not what I want. I suspect I will have to define my own `pagestyle`, but don't know how/can't find a simple answer.

If somebody could help me achieve this or something similar to this style I would be grateful!

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{rose}
}

% ADD bar with sections above header
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
  \section{Section 1}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Section 1: Frame with navigation bar}
  \end{frame}

  \section{Section 2}
  \begin{frame}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \frametitle{Section 2: Frame without navigation bar}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Keep calm and let beamer do it for you]

Beamer has its own solution: `\begin{frame}[plain]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{rose}
}

% ADD bar with sections above header
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
            \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Section 1: Frame with navigation bar}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 2}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \frametitle{Section 2: Frame without navigation bar}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]